# How to replace 'useResult' in graphql with vue and apolo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, graphql, apollo

I have to replace this useResult that is fetching data from graphql

```
const locationOptions = useResult(
       result,
       [],
       ({ getLocations }): Option[] => formatOptions(getLocations)
     )
```

and I want to change it for a computed function like

```
const locationOptions = computed(() => result.value.getLocations ?? [])
```

I was trying to use a `watch` to run the function but it seems not to be working

```
watch(locationOptions, () => {
      formatOptions(locationOptions.value)
    })
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format function already in the computed function:

```js
const locationOptions = computed(() => {
    return result.value?.getLocations ? formatOptions(result.value.getLocations) || []
})
```